# Java : Problems accessing and writing to file

Tags: java, file, exception, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I was testing out writing to files with this code:

```
package files;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileTest1 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        try
        {
            File f = new File("filetest1.txt");
            FileWriter fWrite = new FileWriter(f);
            BufferedWriter fileWrite = new BufferedWriter(fWrite);
            fileWrite.write("This is a test!");
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.print("A FileNotFoundException occurred!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("An IOException occurred!:");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Nothing happens when it is executed.
"This is a test!" is not written, nor the StackTrace or the "A/An [exception] occurred!"...
I don't know what's causing the problem. I have fileTest1.txt in the package right under the file...

Comment: Your code says `filetest1.txt` and your comment says `fileTest1.txt`? Most file systems are case sensitive. You will probably also want to flush your file and then close it.

Comment: Can you show the command you use to run your program? Are you doing it throw some IDE? What platform are you running on? Also, you say "I have fileTest1.txt in the package right under the file" -- can you clarify what that means?

Comment: Also, are you sure you are actually running the program you think you are running? Are you truly running `FileTest1`? Add a `System.println("Hello");` or something as the first line of main. Does it display? Is the working directory different than you expect? Is `filetest1.txt` being created somewhere else?

Answer (score 4):

A `BufferedWriter` does just that, it buffers the output before it is written to the destination.  This can make the `BufferedWriter` faster to use as it doesn't have to write to a slow destination, like a disk or socket, straight away.

The contents will be written when the internal buffer is to full, you `flush` the `Writer` or `close` the writer

Remember, if you open it, you should close it...

For example...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestFileWriter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedWriter fileWrite = null;
            try {
                File f = new File("filetest1.txt");
                System.out.println("Writing to " + f.getCanonicalPath());
                FileWriter fWrite = new FileWriter(f);
                fileWrite = new BufferedWriter(fWrite);
                fileWrite.write("This is a test!");
                fileWrite.flush();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.print("A FileNotFoundException occurred!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    // Note, BufferedWriter#close will also close
                    // the parent Writer...
                    fileWrite.close();
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An IOException occurred!:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader br = null;
            try {
                File f = new File("filetest1.txt");
                System.out.println("Reading from " + f.getCanonicalPath());
                FileReader fReader = new FileReader(f);
                br = new BufferedReader(fReader);
                String text = null;
                while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(text);
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.print("A FileNotFoundException occurred!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    // Note, BufferedWriter#close will also close
                    // the parent Writer...
                    br.close();
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An IOException occurred!:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using Java 7, you may like to take a look at [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: Okay... I fixed the capitolization and added: fileWriter.flush() and fileWriter.close(), but still nothing happens.

Comment: I wrote that in, but still, nothing happened.

Comment: Can I ask you to try my sample code.  Because it works fine for me.  Also, make sure you have write access to the location you are trying to write to...

Comment: The I would suggest that you are trying to write to a location you don't have write access.  Make sure you delete only old `filetest1.txt` files and make sure you are writing to a location you know you can write to

Comment: I think OP is checking a different file with the same name, and not the file that's being written to.

Comment: @MadProgrammer A permissions issues would generate an exception.

Comment: @user2604533: Can you show the command you use to run your program? Are you doing it through some IDE? What platform are you running on? Also, you say "I have fileTest1.txt in the package right under the file" -- can you clarify what that means? Are you sure you are actually running the program you think you are running? Are you truly running `FileTest1`? Add a `System.println("Hello");` or something as the first line of main. Does it display? Is the working directory different than you expect? Is `filetest1.txt` being created somewhere else?

Comment: @JasonC Not on Windows 7 :P - Had this problem, took us two weeks to figure it out :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't ever recall running into a problem like that on Windows 7, but I 100% believe it.

Comment: @user2604533 I've updated my example to print the absolute path of the file being written to so you know, without a doubt, where the file is begin written.  I've also added a read test to read the file back in

Comment: If an exception is not being thrown due to an access denied error, perhaps the file exists but is being held open by some other process; maybe a previous run of his program or a text editor. He does say he already has a "filetest1.txt" somewhere.

Comment: @JasonC Our application was trying to write files into the `Program Files` directory as a normal user and the files just wouldn't write, even though `File#canWrite` was returning `true` - it turns out to be a bug in Java with the UAC - I'd like those two weeks of my life back :P

Comment: Strange. Deleted the filetest1.txt file from the package explorer in eclipse, then looked it up in the search bar to find it still existing, with This is a test! written in it, but i cannot edit it further...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Fascinating; and I'm filing that Java/UAC (non)interaction a way. You may have saved me two weeks at some unknown point in the future. I generally disable UAC immediately out of the box on every machine I configure.

Comment: @user2604533: You didn't say you were viewing it in the Eclipse browser! Eclipse just stinks sometimes about updating resources that are modified outside the editor... I'd just clean your project then restart Eclipse and see if things make more sense after that.

Comment: @JasonC Yeah, our dev machines had the UAC disable, so worked fine for us to, but when we tried to deploy to a client machine it broke...:P

Comment: @MadProgrammer You have my deepest condolences.

Comment: @JasonC I got it :) I saw in the start menu that whenever i ran the program, it would create a new version of the file in a different place in the eclipse project, so I put it there and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

After

```
fileWrite.write("This is a test!");
```

you have to `flush()` the writer. To avoid leaking of resources you should also `close()` the writer (which automatically flushes it).

So you need to add:

```
fileWrite.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `BufferedWriter.flush()` and `BufferedWriter.close()`. Additional info here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html

Answer (score 0):

You must call `close()` or at least `flush()` on the writer in order for the buffer to be really written to the file.

Comment: You should **always** close any resource you open, this can cause problems later - IMHO

Comment: I agree, and I would even do that in a `finally` to be really sure. But the question was why the data is not visible, and that can be reached via `flush()` alone.

Comment: (nit pick) The whole problem could actually be solved by just calling `close`, which not only helps solve the OP's problem, but demonstrates good practices.  If the OP was writing to a `Socket`, it would defiantly agree with adding `flush` - IMHO